# Configuring SSL for subdomains that use Elastic Beanstalk and LightSail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I've been able to set up an SSL certificate with AWS's Certificate Manager and use it for two Elastic Beanstalk environments. One is on example.com and another for dev.example.com. Https works fine for both.

Now, we need to replace example.com with a LightSail WordPress install. The current example.com Elastic Beanstalk environment is moving to another subdomain.

I'm not familiar with LightSail and the docs seem to only cover setting DNS records inside LightSail itself, and from not Route 53. At least when referring to SSL.

The docs do mention that you can create an A record in Route 53 and point it to the LightSail static IP address, which I have done, but the https is invalid. Presumably, I need to assign the SSL certificate somehow, but I haven't had any luck figuring this out.

Do I need to create a load balancer within LightSail, or is there another way to accomplish having one domain in Route 53 pointed to different types of AWS products like this using the same SSL certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to assign the SSL certificate somehow, but I haven't had any luck figuring this out.

The ACM certs can only be used on a load balancer, API gateway and CloudFront distribution. They **can't be used** on a instance.

There are **two options** to rectify the issue:

- Use [load balancer with your lightsale](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-lightsail-load-balancers). With this you can just install your ACM cert on the balancer provided.
- Setup SSL certificate on the instance. Since you can't use ACM for that, you have to get a **third party** certificate for that. A popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/ which provides free public certificates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. After looking into the LightSail load balancer option a little more, the extra cost defeats the purpose of not going with Elastic Beanstalk. LightSail and Let's Encrypt works for now.